# Mips assembly, "function calls" and storing return addresses onto the stack

Tags: function, sorting, assembly, return, mips

This is hopefully a quick question for someone who understands this. But my problem is that I have an assignment, to use selection sort with a variety of methods, and I'm trying to sort out how to use the stack for saving the return address. My problem is that I can get it to go all the way to the last load return address code block, but then I get a bad address in data/stack read, can someone point out as to where I may have messed up in saving to the stack? Thank you very much!

```
main:
 sub $sp, $sp, 4
 sw $ra, ($sp)
 jal sort

 j exit

swap:
 sub $sp, $sp, 8
 sw $fp, 4($sp)
 add $fp, $sp, 4
 sw $ra, ($fp)

 lw $ra, ($fp)
 jr $ra

min:
 sub $sp, $sp, 8
 sw $fp, 4($sp)
 add $fp, $sp, 4
 sw $ra, ($fp)

 lw $ra, ($fp)
 jr $ra

sort:
 sub $sp, $sp, 8
 sw $fp, 4($sp)
 add $fp, $sp, 4
 sw $ra, ($fp)

 jal min

 jal swap

 lw $ra, ($fp)        <---- Bad address in data/stack read Exception
 lw $fp, 4($fp)
 jr $ra

exit:

 li $v0, 10                 #exit
 syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

The general convention is to store on the stack whatever registers can be overwritten. So if in sort procedure you want to save `$ra` then you need to reserve 1 word on stack. After doing all calculations before returning from the procedure you need to restora `$ra` and the stack pointer:

```
sort:
   addi $sp, $sp, -4
   sw $ra, 0($sp)   # saves $ra on stack

   # do calculations
sort_end:
   lw $ra, 0($sp)
   addi $sp, $sp, 4
   jr $ra
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to use the frame pointer too?
You are making the stack usage in a quite complicated way.

```
swap:
 sub $sp, $sp, 8 ; room for 2 words
 sw $fp, 4($sp)  ; store sp in the first
 add $fp, $sp, 4 ; fp = sp + 4 ? Why?
 sw $ra, ($fp)  ; store return address

 lw $ra, ($fp)  ; get return address - leave the fp and sp alone
 jr $ra         ; return, and leave the sp and fp unbalanced
```

Now, you shoudl handle the stack frame either in the caller or callee to keep it clear.
Both making a new frame, and removing it when done with the subroutine.

In sort you call both min and swap, and both of then change both sp and fp without restoring them.

[This](http://www.cs.uaf.edu/~cs301/notes/Chapter9/node11.html) might shed some light...

[edit]

If you insist using frames:

```
push ra
push fp
fp = sp
{ push local variables }

do the deed

sp = fp
pop fp
pop ra
ret
```

this way you have the fp-chain, and if your stack gets corrupted, you still can return
fine. You don't need to push sp, because the sp is stored in fp.

Comment: Thank you for your awnser, I am just really confused on how to use the stack in the first place, and when and where to store things. so when I do (add $fp, $sp, 4), do I even need to do this?

Comment: You don't need the stack frames unless you need to traverse the call tree.